# quartz job suspended while creating httpclient

Tags: quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have created a quartz job, but I have seen that when I want to create a HttpClient from that job, it gets suspended when the program reaches the line

```
CloseableHttpClient clientToPost = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you please add more code?

Comment: @highonprogramming Thanks for your reply, to see the the code please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800162/quartz-scheduler-doing-a-http-post

Comment: Oh, why didn't you just edit this question? I guess you should delete this one now, and leave the question with more details.

Comment: @highonprogramming Sure..I will do that..but can you please help me?